# How to use Model in specific file in lib directory on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

```
I want to use model in specific file in lib directory in rails 5
for example:
```

> lib/app.rb

```
i want to use all models in this file
How can i do?
```

I used `require 'models/post'`

but i received `Post::User not defined`, because i used `belongs_to :user` in Post model

when i added `require 'models/user'` then i received `devise not defined`
so i need require all models.

Comment: I have no idea what this post is asking. Can you please clarify? If you are referring to true rails "models" they belong in `app/models/model_name_here.rb` so that they can be auto loaded.

Comment: you can try ```include App``` and define app.rb as ```module App ... end```

Comment: because i want to use `faye/websocket` and `eventmachine` then use `puma ./lib/app.rb -p 9292` for run it.
i used Post model, because i want save something from response websocket

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Rails is to have one file per class. So, if you have models Foo and Bar, Rails would try to load foo.rb and bar.rb for you automatically.

You can have multiple models defined in the same file but such a setup won't get autoloaded for you transparently. You have to require the file manually:

```
require 'app'
```

You can do this in your controller, for example.